# Verify contraction and uniform continuity of the function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Verify contraction and uniform continuity of the function:
$f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$  $\;\forall x\in(0,1)$

// 
$f'(x)=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ which is not bounded as $x$ tends to $1$
so can I conclude it is not contraction?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @cmk this is I've tried (edited)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(f(x))=x$, which contradicts the contractivity on the interval in just another way.

Continuity on $[0,1]$ implies uniform continuity, using $|\sqrt{u}-\sqrt{v}|\le\sqrt{|u-v|}$ one can show Hölder continuity with exponent $\frac12$.

Comment: $f(f(x))$ for this case should be $x$.

Comment: @KumarNilesh : Thanks, that what I meant to write and what the following conclusion is based on, no idea how that typo happened.

Comment: How do you conclude that this condition violates contractivity? I have not seen the use of this condition to disprove contractivity before .

Comment: If $f$ is contracting on some subinterval $J\subset(0,1)$, then by this identity it has to be expanding on $f(J)$, so it can not be globally contracting.